# ASP.NET Webforms with Sitecore 10.2

Tags: webforms

Last year we have upgraded our Sitecore instance to version 9.3. We still have some renderings developed in ASP.Net Webforms (otherwise we are using ASP.Net MVC). Now we want to upgrade to Sitecore 10.2. My question is that does ASP.Net Webform work with Sitecore 10.2 or are there any limitations if I use existing ASP.Net Webforms renderings with Sitecore 10.2?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Sitecore 10.2 works with ASP.Net Webforms renderings.

If you install clean Sitecore 10.2 - you will see that home page is built using layout(/layouts/Sample Layout.aspx) and sublayout(/layouts/Sample Inner Sublayout.ascx). It means that there should not be any limitations on the usage of ASP.Net Webforms.